# BibLateX/Biber is incorrectly sorting entries with hyphens in their respective author's last name

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation, biber, sorting

**UPDATE 2**

I now finally understand that this behaviour is indeed a feature that is to be modified according to need. Thank you very much to @moewe for educating me on this. I have now set his/her answer as the accepted answer as it is much more complete than the previous one. **In summary, Biber allows you to fine-tune the behaviour of sorting. Please look at the accepted answer to this question for more details and pointers.**

**UPDATE 1**

As per page 22 of the Biber documentation, I can somewhat confirm the explanations of Benedikt and Werner. It does seem that the characters before the hyphen are considered as prefixes. But here's where it gets more interesting - this only happens when there are **exactly two characters preceding the hyphen**. I confirmed this by trying 1 character (`A-Masri`, `D-Masri`), 2 characters (`Al-Masri`, `Ax-Masri`), and 3-characters (`Ala-Masri`). The sorting works correctly for the 1 character and 3 character trials. It seems to me that there is no real practical fix to the engine code. **Thus, my recommendation (for now) to others facing this issue is to rely on the `sortname` workaround.**

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

I am observing incorrect behaviour in the sorting (by author name) of my bibliography entries. I have an entry whose main author's last name (the sorting key) contains a hyphen. This seems to cause the engine to discard everything up to the hyphen as part of the key.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@inproceedings{maleshkova2010investigating,
  title={Investigating web apis on the world wide web},
  author={Maleshkova, Maria and Pedrinaci, Carlos and Domingue, John},
  booktitle={Web Services (ECOWS), 2010 IEEE 8th European Conference on},
  pages={107--114},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{al2007wsce,
  title={WSCE: A crawler engine for large-scale discovery of web services},
  author={Al-Masri, Eyhab and Mahmoud, Qusay H.},  % Notice the name here
  booktitle={Web Services, 2007. ICWS 2007. IEEE International Conference on},
  pages={1104--1111},
  year={2007},
  organization={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\nocite{*}

% ========= %

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This results in the following (incorrect) output:

[image: Incorrect sorting by lastname]

I discovered that removing the hyphen in `Al-Masri` rectifies the sorting. So it seems that **with the hyphen** the engine thinks the name is `Masri`, which is incorrect.

Is this a bug or a feature? If the former, how can this be fixed? If the latter, how can I work around it?

Comment: Consider this a *feature*, as you can use `sortname = {...}` to specify a specific way of sorting the entry in question. For example, try adding `sortname = {AlMasri}` to the entry (see p 26 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

Comment: I feel you may be (only slightly) misunderstanding my question about bug vs. feature. While the sortname field is an excellent workaround (as per the suggestions of Benedikt Bauer and yourself; and thanks for the pointer to the documentation), the real problem is with the hyphen.

As per ASCII, the hyphen is lexicographically lower in order than the English alphabets (am I even correct?). Hence, the Al-Masri entry should appear before the Maleshkova entry.

Benedikt's explanation of Biber treating the part before the hyphen as a prefix makes sense. Do you have any comment on this, any chance?

Comment: See p 22 of the [`biber` documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.8/documentation/biber.pdf/download) where it mentions something about constructing hyphenated names. As such, I think `biblatex` desides sort based on `M` rather than `A`, and passes this information to `biber`.

Comment: Bingo, I would have never found that section by myself. Thank you very much. Up-voted.

Comment: @Werner I don't think that solution will work in general even though it will in this case. I'm not sure what the rules are but I'm pretty sure that `Al-Masri` ought not be sorted identically to `Almasri` which is what that workaround does. That page of the manual suggests that by default `biber` should not be ignoring `Al-` because it is only meant to ignore lowercase prefixes.

Comment: According to the Biber documentation that Werner pointed out, it seems that there is no real fix because it is neither a bug nor is it a feature. I did some more experiments and will report it back in my OP. Please take a look at it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in your edited question this is not so much a bug, but a feature (luckily though for us, it is a feature that can be controlled and customised).

Biber allows for sorting exceptions as well as for exceptions when creating initials. These exceptions can be declared with `\DeclareNosort{}` and `\DeclareNoinit{}` respectively.

If the commands are not present, Biber will default to

```
\DeclareNosort{
  % strip prefixes like 'al-' when sorting names
  \nosort{type_names}{\regexp{\A\p{L}{2}\p{Pd}}}
  % strip diacritics when sorting names
  \nosort{type_names}{\regexp{[\x{2bf}\x{2018}]}}
}

\DeclareNoinit{
  % strip lowercase prefixes like 'al-' when generating initials from names
  \noinit{\regexp{\b\p{Ll}{2}\p{Pd}}}
  % strip diacritics when generating initials from names
  \noinit{\regexp{[\x{2bf}\x{2018}]}}
}
```

As explained in the  comments there, the first line will strip `al-`/`Al-` prefixes (the regex matches two letters at the begin of a string followed by a punctuation mark), so we can just get rid of those lines to obtain

```
\DeclareNosort{
  % strip diacritics when sorting names
  \nosort{type_names}{\regexp{[\x{2bf}\x{2018}]}}
}

\DeclareNoinit{
  % strip diacritics when generating initials from names
  \noinit{\regexp{[\x{2bf}\x{2018}]}}
}
```

This will sort the list as expected, as "al-"/"Al-" prefixes are no longer ignored, furthermore they will also be considered for initials, if you do not want that, just leave out the `\DeclareNoinit{}` command all together.

See also §4.5.6 *Controlling Name Initials Generation* and §4.5.7 *Fine Tuning Sorting*, p. 164-166 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

If you do not want to put this line in your preamble whenever you write a document, you might consider `biblatex.cfg` or a Biber config file (more about that in the [Biber documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf), §3.1 *Options and config file*, p. 9)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{maleshkova2010investigating,
  title={Investigating web apis on the world wide web},
  author={Maleshkova, Maria and Pedrinaci, Carlos and Domingue, John},
  booktitle={Web Services (ECOWS), 2010 IEEE 8th European Conference on},
  pages={107--114},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{al2007wsce,
  title={WSCE: A crawler engine for large-scale discovery of web services},
  author={Al-Masri, Eyhab and Mahmoud, Qusay H.},  % Notice the name here
  booktitle={Web Services, 2007. ICWS 2007. IEEE International Conference on},
  pages={1104--1111},
  year={2007},
  organization={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\DeclareNosort{
  % strip diacritics when sorting names
  \nosort{type_names}{\regexp{[\x{2bf}\x{2018}]}}
}

\DeclareNoinit{
  % strip diacritics when generating initials from names
  \noinit{\regexp{[\x{2bf}\x{2018}]}}
}

\begin{document}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As an explanation, I can only imagine, that `biber` or `biblatex` are treating the "al" part of the name as some kind of name prefix, similar to the "de" in dutch names.

I am quite sure to remember that there is a more global option as well, but I don't have the time now to work it out. As a simple workaround for a single name, you can just give the respective item a `sortname` field. Try the following entry:

```
@inproceedings{al2007wsce,
  title={WSCE: A crawler engine for large-scale discovery of web services},
  author={Al-Masri, Eyhab and Mahmoud, Qusay H.},
  booktitle={Web Services, 2007. ICWS 2007. IEEE International Conference on},
  pages={1104--1111},
  year={2007},
  organization={IEEE},
  sortname = {Almasri}, % This field will be used for sorting
}
```