# Biber Log: "\x{2018}" does not map to iso-8859-1, what does it mean

Tags: biber, characters

I'm currently working on a document and everything is working fine.

I'm just a curious what these Messages `"\x{2018}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\[...]\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949.` from Biber mean. Are those warnings without explicit declaration? According to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171492/biblatex-biber-is-incorrectly-sorting-entries-with-hyphens-in-their-respective-a) \x{2018} might be "-", but i don't know if that is important.

The complete log from Texstudio is below.

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is 'Masterarbeit.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Masterarbeit.bcf'
INFO - Found 17 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Masterarbeit.bib' for section 0
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Masterarbeit.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'English_United States.1252' default tailoring 'variable =     shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'anyt' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'English_United States.1252'
INFO - Writing 'Masterarbeit.bbl' with encoding 'latin1'
INFO - Output to Masterarbeit.bbl

"\x{2018}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949. 
"\x{2019}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949. 
"\x{2018}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949. 
"\x{2019}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949. 
"\x{2a7d}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949. 
"\x{2018}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949. 
"\x{2019}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949. 
"\x{2018}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949. 
"\x{2019}" does not map to iso-8859-1 at C:\Users\Seb\AppData\Local\Temp\par-536562\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 949.

Prozess endete normal
```

Edit: Jukka K. Korpela solved the puzzle. Just for completeness (and other searching) a bit more background:  The failure was all in one line, because it was in the entry @abstract. It was generated from zotero and all the characters that ereg correctly identified where in that single entry. It didn't matter in my document, because i don't use the @abstract in my bibliography.

Comment: Check your bib-file, it is probably a bad character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\x{2018}` stands for U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (‘), the character used e.g. as an opening single quotation mark in English (‘this way’). It indeed does not map to iso-8859-1, i.e. iso-8859-1 has no code position for it. It does map to windows-1252, but presumably “latin1” as used here refers to iso-8859-1. You should check the output (does it show this character right?) and, if needed, change the encoding.

Comment: Just for completeness, `\x{2a7d}` stands for “U+2A7D LESS-THAN OR SLANTED EQUAL TO” and `\x{2019}` stands for “U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK”. The remedy is to change, in the `.bib` file, `‘` with `\``, `’` with `'` and `⩽` with `$\le$`.